# PyQt - how to rerender window

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, rendering

I am new to PyQt and Qt at all and I have a problem with window rendering or updating or how to call it. Problem is that when I call QWidget.show(), none of added components after are displayed. Here is a simple code, where in **init**(), there is called self.show(). First QLabel item is displayed and the second one is not. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel
import sys

class MyGui(QWidget):

    box = {}

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(200, 400)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:#000000")

        self.box["top"] = QLabel(self)
        self.box["top"].setFixedSize(200, 200)
        self.box["top"].setStyleSheet("background-color:red")
        self.box["top"].move(0,0)
        self.show()
        self.box["botom"] = QLabel(self)
        self.box["botom"].setFixedSize(200, 200)
        self.box["botom"].setStyleSheet("background-color:green")
        self.box["botom"].move(0,200)
        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    my_app = MyGui()
    my_app.show()
    
    try:
        sys.exit(app.exec())
    except SystemExit:
        print("Closing window..")
```

Screenshots of GUI window:

With self.show()

[image: With self.show()]

Without self.show()

[image]

Comment: Why are you calling `self.show()` when you already do `my_app.show()` later?

Comment: @perivesta I want to call my_app.show() defaultely. Point of this question is that I do not know, how to make new components (added to window after show() is called) appear in the window. That is why I demonstrate the problem with self.show(). When I call only self.show() and not my_app.show(), problem remains.

Comment: That's the expected behaviour.  Roughly speaking, when you change the parent widget's visibility the visibility of existing child widgets may be affected.  But child widgets added after that do not necessarily inherit the parent's visibility.

Comment: And what is proper way of adding components at runtime and make them visible?

Comment: Just call `self.box["botom"].show()` explicitly.  As an aside, you might also want to look at using [layouts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/layout.html) rather than managing child geometries manually.

Comment: Really, the answer is to [use layouts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/layout.html), since that will make it unnecessary to explicitly call `show()` (and also make lots of other things easier to do).